# jQuery selector :first

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select text from a list. I want to select "First level text" but not "Second level text".

```
<div class="selectedText"></div>
<ul>
  <li>First level text
    <ul>
      <li>Second level text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

My bad selector:

```
var firstLI = $('ul').find('li:first');
$('.selectedText').text(firstLI.text());
```

It pastes contents of the nested UL into my textbox.
How can I get only the LI text?  Thanks.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eYa3G/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you just want the first text node of that element.

```
$("ul li:first").contents().first().text();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8NzUT/).

This gets the first node's text, which is a text node in your case.

Alternatively, if jQuery was in short supply...

```
document.querySelector("ul li:first-child").firstChild.data;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mea6x/).

Comment: @JenniferMichelle A lot of browsers have a `console` object. You can `log` on this object, and see the results in the browser's console. There is also `warn`, `error` and a bunch of other useful methods.

Answer (score 0):

this is one way to get text of li element

```
alert( $('ul li:first').clone().children().remove().end().text());
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eYa3G/6/)

Full Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

 var data= $('ul li:first').clone().children().remove().end().text();
   $('.selectedText').text(data);
});
```